# Booking.com just got added to chrome shortcuts on new tab page

Tags: google-chrome

Today, on the new tab page of [AVG Secure Browser](https://www.avg.com/secure-browser) (A version of Chrome, with security extensions), booking.com was added to the shortcuts/favourite-links.
I didn't put it there, I didn't go to booking.com at all, I didn't hover over a link to booking.com, or even see a link going there.
I went for a scan with my anti-virus, it didn't find anything!
It seems so random, why it's booking.com and not any other website?
It was added without my knowledge, somehow?!

[image]

Comment: You're using Chrome.  That's part of Google's business model.  The better question is why is this the first time you've noticed such things added for your convenience?  If you like Chrome and don't appreciate these kinds helpful suggestions, try Chromium or a Chromium-based browser.

Comment: I use [AVG secure browser](https://www.avg.com/secure-browser), which is a version of Chrome, made by [AVG](http://avg.com), but I didn't realize that it would be important. Anyways, the problem isn't the new tab page, it's the shortcut/favorite-link added to the new-tab page.

Comment: First of all it's not the one on the toolbar, it's the one below the Google sign, [here](https://imgur.com/vao2U8c). Also I didn't visit the page.

Comment: I have never had anything randomly added to my Chrome browser before. Are you sure you didn't install something? You said it was the AVG version, maybe they added it for advertising revenue.

Comment: @HazardousGlitch You could be right for advertising revenue, but I doubt it. And AVG would probably say they sponsor it or something.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior in Chrome.

These are not favorites, and most other browsers do exactly the same thing (Yea, Firefox does this too).

This is simply the browser noting sites you've visited, or if you've been to a lot of sites, the sites you've visited most or frequently, and making it easy to get back to.

Nothing nefarious going on here.

If you don't want this, you can change your homepage to something else.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, but I didn't go on the page at all. I didn't even know booking.com existed. But then I clicked went to it *after* it appeared in the shortcuts.